# Unable to run Debug version of node-webkit in WebStorm 9

Tags: webstorm, node-webkit

I have node-webkit application that have the following entry poing:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function bodyOnLoad(){
            window.location.assign('http://localhost:3000/');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="bodyOnLoad()">
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My nodejs side listening 3000 port on localhost and have the following strucure:

```
// start.js
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send(ok);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

I've created run/debug configuration and tried to run onses. Run configuration starts well but Debug one throws the following error and don't start node-webkit application:

```
[3736:1128/105652:FATAL:render_process_host_impl.cc(479)] Check failed: !g_exited_main_message_loop. 

Process finished with exit code -2147483645
```

And my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "nw",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "node-main": "start.js",
}
```

Please help me with my problem.

Comment: res.send(ok); -- can you try responding with more content?

Comment: yes. Actyally I render the view page and `res.send('ok')` just an example

Comment: what is your node-webkit version? looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14378

Comment: @lena yes. I have the same error. So is it bug of node-webkit@0.11 ?

Comment: rather a problem of WebStorm debugger incompatibility with this particular version... Until youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14378 is fixed, I'd suggest downgrading your node-webkit